# cloudformation ecs force new deployement

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What is the equivalent of --force-new-deployment flag in cloudformation ?
(aws ecs update-service --cluster  --service  --force-new-deployment)

In my cloudformation template, my docker image tag is latest. However I want to be able to force the redeployment if I replay the stack.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of CloudFormation as just a provisioning service or an orchestrator.

Specifying an [Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-image) as `repository-url/image:tag` will definitely fetch the specified image with specific tag from your repo but only upon a stack operation. Once a stack operation is finished, any changes to service will be depending on the next stack operation.

What you can do here is either having either

- [Cloudwatch Event based rule targeting a Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) whenever there is an image upload to ECR.
- Or in case of using some other repo than ECR, have a hook configured in a way that will invoke `update-service --cluster --service --force-new-deployment ...` command whenever there is a new image upload.

**Considerations:**

- This can lead your stack being in `DRIFTED` status.
- Just make sure to keep your stack's [Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-image) property's value in sync with the latest one running within service, whenever you plan to update the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I came up with to force a deploy after a stack update if needed.  The service name is the same as the stack name, so if yours is different you will need to adjust accordingly.

```
START_TIME=`date +%s`
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name $STACK_NAME [other options]
LAST_DEPLOY=`aws ecs describe-services --services $STACK_NAME --query "services[0].deployments[?status=='PRIMARY'].createdAt" --output text`
if [ "$START_TIME" -gt "${LAST_DEPLOY%.*}" ]; then aws ecs update-service --service $STACK_NAME --force-new-deployment; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I have been able to come up with is to change my healthcheck from curl -f to curl --fail and back to force a new deployment. Not ideal but it works.

I'd be interested in a better way, ideally built in to CloudFormation too.